# React Native, simulator and browser show image differently

Tags: react-native

While the style looks correct on the iOS simulator
[simulator view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3orq.jpg)

but in the browser the images are all collapsed 
[browser view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxC0O.png)

what could cause the images to render differently?

Comment: I think Problem is your image size please check these size , and define image size thanks :-)

Comment: I gave image size a dynamic value (width: 100% and height: 80%) and yes, once after I gave img a defined size, it looks fine in browser, but then it doesn't achieve the look I'd like in mobile. Can't we have dynamic values set for image ?

Comment: You can check in react native which platform is currently  means detect is Android & IPhone & web and set your condition  according to your design , hope its work thanks :-)